# problems building with ADT r14

Tags: android, adt

just updated the SDK and the ADT after it was released with the ICS announcement - but having some problems building my projects - even after cleaning/refreshing/restarting eclipse this persists.

```
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActionBar$LayoutParams;
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:486)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:455)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:394)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:418)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:329)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:206)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:179)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:729)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:602)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:321)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:396)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.build(ProjectHelper.java:869)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:146)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:854)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:703)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:928)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1132)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2011-10-19 15:24:51 - gobandroid] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Comment: Are you using the compatibility library along with ics sdk?

Comment: yea - updated the sdk first and then the ADT forced an update too

Comment: @ligi i had the same isuse ... do you have "Project Library"(not only jar) referenced in your project ?

Comment: @selvin: yes I do an I am also seing the wind coming from this direction - changelog says that there are major changes in that field too

Comment: @ligi on Project => RMouseB->Android Tools->Fix Project Properties

Comment: @selvin: great! thanks for the hint - it works now - when you post that as an regular answer I will accept it and you get the credits - thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem with a project that contained references to two Library Projects.  For mine the Fix Project Properties didn't help.  So instead I opened up the project properties and removed the references to the Library Projects, closed the properties, and then re-added them.  I also had to remove the links to the source of those projects as the conversion seemed to munge it in some way.

Answer (score 2):

Theres a bug report for that: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20398

And temporary solution:
http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/fix-the-conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-with-adt-14

Answer (score 0):

"Fix Project Properties" didn't work for me. I tried to close the project, manually edit .classpath and  .project files and remove references to library project (from classpathentry, projects and linkedResources xml elements). Then I opened project in Eclipse again, re-added reference to library project again and it finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I have the same kind of problem.

Since the Update of ADT/SDK to r14 I am **not able** to Build my project too.

I have a simple project which is compiling well (Sure it is just a shortcut, yehaa \o/)

But a complex project with:
1 User Library
1 Referenced Library

I have this error: Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space

I tried many Eclipse configuration but without any improvement.
I tried, with install SDK from scratch and Eclipse Indigo + ADT from scratch too it is the same pain.

I am really disapointed because we will be many on that case in my company, that is very critical for us, and I am very angry against Google who release these tools without enought tests or f** documentation !!!!
except: http://developer.android.com/sdk/tools-notes.html

What you can try it is to create new project from scratch and copy src (and res) into.